# Tampermonkey - Form Dropdown selection with autofill verification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Filling out a signup page that checks to see if it was auto filled. I spent half the day and fount a code that worked for the text boxes posted by wOxxOm.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[4].focus();
document.execCommand('selectAll');
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'My City');
```

Well below this I have `document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[5]`.  This is a dropdown state selection. When I use the `execCommand` to send `[5]` letters they are sent back to `[4]`. I think it has to do with the `.focus()` not working on the dropdown selection. I have tried everything from jnode changes, val changes, and `triggerMouseEvent`. Also `getelementBy`/`ID` or `NAME` is not possible except thru option `form-control` with a number selection as they change every new visit except for `form-control[1]`-`[8]`.

```
        waitForKeyElements (".form-control:has(option[value=AL])", selectDropdown);

function selectDropdown (jNode) {
    var evt = new Event ("click");
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);

    jNode.val('AK');

    evt = new Event ("change");
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);
}
```

I posted this because it works until I click submit then the input is removed. I do believe a mouse selection should be able to work, but I am just at a loss right now. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the answer, I used

`var targNode    = document.getElementsByClassName("formInput")[2];
targNode.classList.remove ("NotVerified");
targNode.classList.add ("Verified hasinteracted");`

Then just set each dropmenu with a simple value and verification values where set.. Just incase someone else needs an answer for the same question.